# Chebyshev inequality- Conclusion

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f$ be an extended real valued measurable function defined on $X$. I have already seen that 
$$
\mu\left(\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}\right)\leq \frac{1}{t}\int_X |f|~d\mu 
$$
for any $t\in (0,\infty)$.

CONCLUDE that the measure of the set $$\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}$$

is finite for every $t$.

Comment: I think you need additional hypotheses. Otherwise take the real line with Lebesgue measure, $f(x)=x$ and $t=0$.

Comment: t can not be 0! It must be a positive number

Comment: I agree with @JyotirmoyBhattacharya. Take $t=1$ is his example and see how $\mu\{ |f(x)|\ge 1\}=+\infty$. You probably forgot to mention that $f$ must be $L^1$.

Comment: If $f\in L^1(X)$, that's ok.

Comment: We can not conclude for any of the given hypotheses that f is L1?

Comment: unfortunately, no. measurable does not imply integrable and measurable is the only hypoteses that you have here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to suppose that $f\in L'$

Then we know that $f$ is integrble if and only if $\int_X|f|d\mu$ is finite.

Therefore, the integral (finite) divided by a finite value is always going to be finite